# hyperlink contains root url "localhost/someurl/" if "http://" is is not given in url asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page called references which contains all the hyperlinks of various guidelines. These references can be added via admin panel. But the problem if the hyperlink doesn't contain "http://" prefix it redirects to "localhost:[somePortNo]/[myHyperLink]" instead of "http://[myHyperLink]"

the razor code which I have used is

```
<a href="@reference.HyperLink" target="_blank">@reference.HyperLink</a>
```

It is a very minor problem, but its taking a lot of time for me to resolve.

Comment: Making sure they are prefixed with http:// when saving them on the admin panel might be the solution your looking for.

Comment: yes i can do that, but dont want to enforce it in the application. so i was wondering if there is any function or something which takes care of such hypelinks in razor.

Comment: if you mean by enforcing that you don't want to save them prefixed in the database, then you could apply the prefix just before returning the view? Something similar like `if (reference.indexOf("http://") == -1) reference = "http://" + reference;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the standard behavior of web browsers. If the URL in href="URL" does not start with "http://" or "https://" or "//" it assumes you are navigating to a link on the current website.

You must prefix with http:// or https:// or //

You could try this:

```
<a href="@(reference.HyperLink.StartsWith("http") ? reference.HyperLink : "http://"+reference.HyperLink)" target="_blank">@reference.HyperLink</a>
```

Comment: It might very well also just start with "//".